# react TypeError: o.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

**guys iam new in react js. so guys help this rectify**

```
1 of 4 errors on the page
TypeError: o.map is not a function
value
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/react-slideshow-image/src/fade.js:180

  177 | {arrows &&
  178 |   showPreviousArrow(this.props, this.state.index, this.preFade)}
  179 | <div className="react-slideshow-fade-wrapper" ref={this.wrapper}>
> 180 |   <div
      | ^  181 |     className="react-slideshow-fade-images-wrap"
  182 |     ref={wrap => (this.divsContainer = wrap)}
  183 |   >

componentDidMount
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/src/Home.js:15

  12 |     try {
  13 |         const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Banner/'); // fetching the data from api, before the page loaded
  14 |         const books = await res.json();
> 15 |         this.setState({
     | ^  16 |             books
  17 |     });
  18 | } catch (e) {

./src/index.js
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/src/index.js:7

   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,

__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/webpack/bootstrap:784

  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;

fn
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

1
http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2400:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/webpack/bootstrap:784

  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;

checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/webpack/bootstrap:45

  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 

webpackJsonpCallback
C:/Users/Ravindrakumara/Desktop/books/webpack/bootstrap:32

  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;

**(anonymous function)
```

http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:63
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
have to pass with slide panel form back**
*--code--*

```
import React,{ Component } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import { Fade } from 'react-slideshow-image';
import 'react-slideshow-image/dist/styles.css'
import Books from "./Books";

class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        books: []
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Banner/'); // fetching the data from api, before the page loaded
            const books = await res.json();
            this.setState({
                books
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

render() {
    
    return (
        
        <div className="slide-container">
            {this.state.books.map(banners => ( 
            <Fade>
                
                    <div className="each-fade" key={banners.id}>
                    <div className="image-container">
                        <img src={banners.banner} className="image-slide" />
                    </div>
                        <h2 className="carousel__title">{banners.headline}</h2>
                    </div>
               
            </Fade> ))}
        </div>
     
    )
}
}
export default Home
```

**it is Carousel and have to display from back-end images**

Comment: Add your code too.

Comment: It's not clear from the error message, but my guess is you're calling `books.map()` before books is set, so you're trying to call map on undefined. Verify that it's present before invoking methods. `books?.map()` or `(books || []).map()`, etc.

Comment: class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        books: []
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Banner/'); // fetching the data from api, before the page loaded
            const books = await res.json();
            this.setState({
                books
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

Comment: Your initial state (`state.books`) is an array, so if it's ever anything *other* than an array then it got updated to not be an array. Check all the places state is updated and validate the value you update with is an array. Don't forget to check the `response.ok` from the fetch request as it still returns a resolved promise even for unsuccessful network requests, i.e. `40X`.

Comment: i have to add code you do can find out easily